# How to apply code to multiple controls at once?

Tags: coding-style, webforms

Im new at ASP.net.
I hope you can tell me the answer about this question.

I have a problem:

```
        if (Convert.ToDouble(txtAnalyseren.Text) > 5.5)
        {
            enough++;
        }
```

I have 7 of these more with all different text-boxes, I need to control if it is a enough or a "notenough" Is there a way to controle this at once?
I don't want to copy and paste this for 7 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be cycling through all of your controls in the page and detect which of them is a textbox:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c is TextBox)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```